# Does someone know what is the classical piece that plays at the very beginning of episode 13 of the first season of Code Geass?

Tags: music, code-geass

I was watching episode 13 of the first season of Code Geass and I really liked the classical song, at least it sounds like it. It plays at the very begging of the episode when they are reviewing what happened.

Answer (score 0):

It's Noblesse oblige by Kohtaro Nakagawa